# MYSQL order by left join existing rows

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have table products and I need search in table by two different ways.

For example search query is 'Yellow bag'

I take this query and found some categories and colors and return it. Then I have

```
SELECT * FROM products where color = color AND categories IN (...) etc..
```

Its worked fine, but sometimes I get much results and I need use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE %yellow% AND name LIKE '%bag%' ...
```

and this SELECT I want use AS order by. So I need to tell GIVE ME ALL results by the first SELECT and ORDER BY exist result founded in the second query.

Because the second query is very simple and I want use it only as helper select.

And I am using Doctrine query builder.

Example data

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE color = yellow AND categories IN (1,2);

1 | YELLOW valise
2 | YELLOW something
3 | YELLOW BAG ------ > this is most relevant result
4 | YELLOW SOMETHING

SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%Yellow bag%';

3 | YELLOW BAG
```

And I need this output

```
3 | YELLOW BAG
1 | YELLOW valise
2 | YELLOW something
...
```

Thanks for help

Comment: It would help to see some sample data, and the expected output.

Comment: Ok, I was updated my answer

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a single query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE color = yellow AND categories IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE '%yellow%' AND name LIKE '%bag%' 
              THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END,
         name
```

;